# Publish TIFF in GeoNode

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, geonode, publishing

I am trying to publish TIFF in GeoNode. The TIFF file has a `.tfw` file.

Uploading directly from GeoNode fails. Then I uploaded to server and published it in GeoServer and it works in GeoServer. I want the layer to be available in data panel in GeoNode. For this I did `geonode updatelayers` but it gives `('Failed to process geotiff_coverage', AttributeError("'Coverage' object has no attribute 'srid'",))`

Then I saved the image as GeoTIFF using QGIS (i.e. without `.tfw` file) but still same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default workspace in geoserver was changed so it didnot work. Setting geonode as default workspace solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the projection (that's what the error message is saying). Try creating a `.prj` file to go with the `.tif` and `.tfw` files if you already know the projection. http://epsg.io will be able to show you what goes in it.

Alternatively, when saving out of QGis be sure to make sure that there is a CRS set for your layer.

Comment: I tried both method but still same errors

Comment: can you publish it directly in GeoServer with out GeoNode? to work out where the error is?

Comment: i can directly publish to geoserver and it works from there, but it doesnot appear in the geonode data panel